# Problem involving reductions of ideals with assumption on characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

I'm reading the paper [A formula for the core of an ideal](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410340) of C. Polini and B. Ulrich and I'm with serious trouble in a passage. Since I guess it is just only smart trick, I decided to ask here.

Some definitions:

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $I$ an ideal of $R$. A subideal $J\subseteq I$ is said a *reduction* of $I$ if there is $n\in \mathbf{N}$ such that $JI^n = I^{n+1}$.

The problem is:

We have a Cohen-Macaulay local ring $R$ with infinite residue field $k$, $I$ an $R$-ideal with $ht(I)=\ell(I)=1$  and $J$ a minimal reduction of $I$. We know that $JI^r = I^{r+1}$. Since $ht(I)=\ell(I)=1$, we know $J$ is a principal ideal generated by a $R$-regular element. The article said that if the $char(k) = 0$ or $char(k)>r$, we have $I^r = \sum_{y \in I}(J,y)^r$.
Well, the inclusion $\supseteq$ is trivial, but I don't have any idea how to prove the other inclusion.

Thanks, any help will be welcome.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I believe the equality follows from a modification of the following statement to your setting. Let $R = Q[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Then $(x_1,\dots,x_n)^r = \{ x^r \mid x \in (x_1,\dots,x_r) \}$. For instance, $(x,y)^2 = (x^2, xy, y^2)$ and once you have $x^2,y^2$, to get $xy$, one can use $(x+y)^2 - x^2 -y^2 = 2xy$.

Comment: Hi, Youngsu. I was thinking in your comment. For example, to conclude $xy \in \sum_{x \in (x_1,...,x_n)}(x^r)$, we have to use $2$ is unity in $R$. In my case, I can't to ensure this.